# SAS Conditional row highlighting with ODS and Proc Print

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I want to turn the **entire row** red for people whose names begin with 'J'.  Is this possible using `proc print`?

```
ods html file=odsout style=htmlblue ;

proc print data=sashelp.class noobs label;  
  var name age;
run;

ods html close;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible with PROC PRINT.  PROC REPORT can generate the identical output but with the rows red, however.

Identical:

```
proc report data=sashelp.class nowd;
columns name age;
run;
```

With red:

```
proc report data=sashelp.class nowd;
columns name age;
compute name;
 if substr(name,1,1)='J' then
     call define(_row_, "style", "style=[backgroundcolor=red]");
endcomp;
run;
```

I would consider it somewhat cleaner to use a style definition of course but for a one-off sort of thing this is easy.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I had a feeling that was the case.